# Unable to get custom MKAnnotationView callout to appear

Tags: objective-c, macos, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm building an OSX application that uses Mapkit, and I'm trying to get a callout to appear when I click on an MKAnnotationView on my map. To do this I'm implementing the MKMapViewDelegate, and the following function :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[LocationPin class]]) {
    LocationPin *returnPin = (LocationPin *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"LocationPin"];
    if (!returnPin){
        returnPin = [LocationPin createLocationPinForMapView:mapView annotation:annotation];
    }
    returnPin.title = annotation.title;
    NSButton *rightButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 80.0)];
    [rightButton setTitle:@"Info"];
    [rightButton setBezelStyle:NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle];
    returnPin.annotation = annotation;
    returnPin.canShowCallout = YES;
    returnPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    return returnPin;
    }
    return nil;
    }
```

The function runs fine everytime I put a new pin down, and I made sure the titles of the pins are not empty or null, but the callout still is not showing up. Anybody have any ideas?

EDIT:
After looking through Anna's response, I realized I misunderstood how to implement the MKAnnotation protocol. I've deleted my LocationPin class, which inherited from MKAnnotationView, and instead added the following class to represent my custom MKAnnotation, with a class inside of it to generate a custom MKAnnotationView:

```
@implementation LocationAnnotation:

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location     {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
    _title = newTitle;
    _coordinate = location;
    }

    return self;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)annotationView {

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"LocAnno"];
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dvd"];

    NSButton *rightButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 80.0)];
    [rightButton setTitle:@"Info"];
    [rightButton setBezelStyle:NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle];

    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return annotationView;
}

@end
```

I've also changed the MKMapViewDelegate function the following way now:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[LocationAnnotation class]]) {

        LocationAnnotation *anno = (LocationAnnotation *)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView *returnPin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"LocAnno"];
        if (!returnPin){
            returnPin = anno.annotationView;
        }
        else {
            returnPin.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return returnPin;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

But the callout still is not appearing. Any help is appreciated.

Edit 2:
As requested, LocationAnnotation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface LocationAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location;
-(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView;



@end
```

Comment: The code is checking if `annotation` is of type `LocationPin` and then creates `returnPin` which is also of type `LocationPin` and returns _that_ as the `MKAnnotationView`?  So the `LocationPin` class is both an annotation model object _and_ a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`?  That seems confusing and odd.  Show how the annotations are created and added to the map.

Comment: Turns out I misunderstood the MKAnnotation protocol, and that may have been causing some confusion. The callouts still are not appearing, but I've designed the classes a little bit better (See the edit). As for how annotations are created and added to the map, my class that inherits from MKMapView, I have a MouseDown handler that gets the coordinates of a click on the map, and creates and adds a new annotation using `[[LocationAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:@"LocationAnno" Location:coord]`

Comment: It looks like there may not be a proper connection between the instance variable `_title` and the `title` property.  Even though `_title` is set in the init method, that might not be the backing instance variable that the `title` property is using (and so `title` remains `nil`).  Can you please show the full LocationAnnotation.h and .m files including all instance variables, properties, and synthesizes?

Comment: I've edit the original post to include the full interface class. When I option-click on the `title` property in my interface class, it tells me that it is a reference to the MKAnnotation delegate class.

Comment: So there's no explicit ivar declared `_title` and no @synthesize?  Try changing `_title = newTitle;` to `_title = [newTitle copy];`.  After the alloc+initWithTitle line, NSLog the title and see what it says: `NSLog(@"title=[%@]", ann.title);`.

Comment: It's having the same behavior. I have `LocationAnnotation *newAnno = [[LocationAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:@"LocationAnno" Location:coord];` followed by the NSLog statement you provided, and it outputs `title=[LocationAnno]`

Comment: Strange, problem must be in some code not shown.  Last attempt: Try removing or commenting out the whole viewForAnnotation delegate method.  The map view should then create a default red pin.  See if tapping on it shows the callout.

Comment: It does still show the red pin, but still no callout. I went and followed this tutorial exactly: [https://bakyelli.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/creating-custom-map-annotations-using-mkannotation-protocol/](https://bakyelli.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/creating-custom-map-annotations-using-mkannotation-protocol/) but it still doesn't show callouts.

Comment: I feel like the problem is that the pin is never getting selected. I also just tried to implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` method: `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view `, with just an NSLog statement inside, and it is never getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I was subclassing MKMapView, which is apparently not recommended by Apple, as it can cause some unwanted behavior.